# What does a working example of dealing with packet fragmentation in C# look like when using the Begin* End* method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, packet, fragmentation

After enough playing with asynchronous socket programming I noticed that the server was receiving chunked payloads (ie: more than one complete payload sitting in the same buffer). So I came up with the following:

```
if (bytes_to_read > 0)
{
    while (bytes_to_read > 0)

        // Get payload size as int.

        // Get payload in byte format.

        // Do something with payload.

        // Decrease the amount of bytes to read.
    }

    // Wait for more data.
}
```

And then I noticed packet fragmentation (ie: what I thought were complete payloads chunked together wasn't always so) which changed the previous code to something like:

```
if (bytes_to_read > 0)
{
    while (bytes_to_read > 0)
    {
        // Get payload size as int.

        // Check if the payload size is less than or equal to the amount of bytes left to read.
        if (payload_size <= bytes_to_read)
        {
            // Get payload in byte format.

            // Do something with payload.

            // Decrease the amount of bytes to read.
        }
        else
        {
            // We received a fragmented payload.
            break;
        }
    }

    if (bytes_to_read == 0)
    {
        // Wait for more data.
    }
    else if (bytes_to_read > 0)
    {
        // Wait for more data where we left off. ***
    }
    else
    {
        // Something awful happened.
    }
}
```

*** I don't even know how to go about this and would like to see code for it. I had an idea that it involved copying the in-completed payload to the beginning of the buffer and then picking up from there.

The pseudo code I included is based on the Begin* End* method I am using (I'm aware that I should be using the *Async set of methods found here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx <- but I think my overall question still applies).

I am seeking the answers to 2 questions--namely:

1. Is this approach correct or am I
   missing something?
2. What does a working example of
   dealing with packet fragmentation in
   C# look like?

EDIT: I'm using raw sockets.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

EDIT: John Saunders and Greg Hewgill have brought up the point of treating data as a stream but that does not provide me with a concrete example of how to deal with the last chunked payload sometimes being fragmented.

EDIT: I have read Jon Skeet's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769045/when-i-send-a-packet-over-tcp-it-is-split-into-two-packets) which is basically along the same lines as the other answers I have seen but it doesn't help me much as I already get what I have to do but not how to do it.

EDIT: To elaborate on what I mean by fragmentation, consider the following the receive buffers:

- 224TEST3foo3bar
- 224TEST3foo3bar224TEST3foo3bar
- 224TEST3foo3bar224TEST3foo
- 3bar224TEST3foo3bar

EDIT: I found [this](http://vadmyst.blogspot.com/2008/03/part-2-how-to-transfer-fixed-sized-data.html) and [this](http://vadmyst.blogspot.com/2008/05/sample-code-for-tcp-server-using.html) which lead me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969996/socket-can-an-asynchronous-receive-returns-without-reading-all-the-bytes-i-aske). [Vadym Stetsiak](http://www.blogger.com/profile/07384298883237115882) has cleared nearly everything up (his was one of the answers I was looking for).

Comment: You haven't said which API you want. TcpClient, or raw sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have to do it yourself, it can be done like so ([reference here](http://vadmyst.blogspot.com/2008/05/sample-code-for-tcp-server-using.html)):

```
/// 
/// Server state holds current state of the client socket
///
class AsyncServerState
{
   public byte[] Buffer = new byte[512]; //buffer for network i/o
   public int DataSize = 0; //data size to be received by the server

   //flag that indicates whether prefix was received
   public bool DataSizeReceived = false;

   public MemoryStream Data = new MemoryStream(); //place where data is stored
   public SocketAsyncEventArgs ReadEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
   public Socket Client;
}

/// 
/// Implements server receive logic
/// 
private void ProcessReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    //single message can be received using several receive operation
    AsyncServerState state = e.UserToken as AsyncServerState;

    if (e.BytesTransferred <= 0 || e.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
    {
        CloseConnection(e);
    }

    int dataRead = e.BytesTransferred;
    int dataOffset = 0;
    int restOfData = 0;

    while (dataRead > 0)
    {
        if (!state.DataSizeReceived)
        {
            //there is already some data in the buffer
            if (state.Data.Length > 0)
            {
                restOfData = PrefixSize - (int)state.Data.Length;
                state.Data.Write(state.Buffer, dataOffset, restOfData);
                dataRead -= restOfData;
                dataOffset += restOfData;
            }
            else if (dataRead >= PrefixSize)
            {   //store whole data size prefix
                state.Data.Write(state.Buffer, dataOffset, PrefixSize);
                dataRead -= PrefixSize;
                dataOffset += PrefixSize;
            }
            else
            {   // store only part of the size prefix
                state.Data.Write(state.Buffer, dataOffset, dataRead);
                dataOffset += dataRead;
                dataRead = 0;
            }

            if (state.Data.Length == PrefixSize)
            {   //we received data size prefix
                state.DataSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.Data.GetBuffer(), 0);
                state.DataSizeReceived = true;

                state.Data.Position = 0;
                state.Data.SetLength(0);
            }
            else
            {   //we received just part of the headers information
                //issue another read
                if (!state.Client.ReceiveAsync(state.ReadEventArgs))
                    ProcessReceive(state.ReadEventArgs);
                    return;
            }
        }

        //at this point we know the size of the pending data
        if ((state.Data.Length + dataRead) >= state.DataSize)
        {   //we have all the data for this message

            restOfData = state.DataSize - (int)state.Data.Length;

            state.Data.Write(state.Buffer, dataOffset, restOfData);
            Console.WriteLine("Data message received. Size: {0}",
                                  state.DataSize);

            dataOffset += restOfData;
            dataRead -= restOfData;

            state.Data.SetLength(0);
            state.Data.Position = 0;
            state.DataSizeReceived = false;
            state.DataSize = 0;

            if (dataRead == 0)
            {
                if (!state.Client.ReceiveAsync(state.ReadEventArgs))
                    ProcessReceive(state.ReadEventArgs);
                    return;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
        else
        {   //there is still data pending, store what we've
            //received and issue another BeginReceive
            state.Data.Write(state.Buffer, dataOffset, dataRead);

            if (!state.Client.ReceiveAsync(state.ReadEventArgs))
                ProcessReceive(state.ReadEventArgs);

            dataRead = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I did not do it exactly this way myself but it helped.

Comment: If you make AsyncServerState itself implement IAsyncResult, it becomes much easier to expose this as a Begin/End pair (so this code's client doesn't have to block either).

Answer (score 3):

This may or may not have anything to do with fragmentation.

In general, the socket will pass you as many bytes at a time as it feels like. Your job is to know how many bytes are in your overall message, and to read them all. Just keep looping until you have all the bytes you need, or until there's an exception.

---

The following code is untested right now. I thought I'd post it before writing the server side of it and testing both.

```
private static string ReceiveMessage(Socket socket)
{
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    var inputBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    var offset = 0;
    var bytesReceived = socket.Receive(
        inputBuffer, offset, BUFFER_SIZE - offset, SocketFlags.None);
    if (bytesReceived < 2)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Receive error");
    }

    var inputMessageLength = inputBuffer[0]*256 + inputBuffer[1];
    offset += bytesReceived;
    var totalBytesReceived = bytesReceived;
    while (bytesReceived > 0 &&
           totalBytesReceived < inputMessageLength + 2)
    {
        bytesReceived = socket.Receive(
            inputBuffer, offset, BUFFER_SIZE - offset, SocketFlags.None);
        offset += bytesReceived;
        totalBytesReceived += bytesReceived;
    }

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
        inputBuffer, 2, totalBytesReceived - 2);
}
```

Note that the receipt of the message length is wrong. The socket layer could give it to me a byte at a time. I'm going to revisit that as part of a refactoring that will receive the count into a separate two-byte buffer, and change the loop into a single do/while.

Comment: This does not really answer my question and I believe what you suggest is something I'm already doing as indicated by the pseudo code above.

Comment: I believe this answer *does* answer your question. At the socket API level, you never need to be concerned about packet fragmentation. TCP does not maintain any kind of boundaries between calls to send(), so the receiver cannot know how many bytes were passed in each call to send(). The receiver just receives an unannotated stream of bytes, all mashed together.

Comment: My question specifically called for presentation of a working example--and preferably one that completes the pseudo code above (or something better).

Comment: You've got a point. But my point was that your pseudo-code is overly complex. The code you actually need is simple enough for you to figure out on your own - so simple that I didn't feel the need to write my first socket-level program in a decade.

Comment: I also think it's overly complex hence me asking if my approach was correct or if I was I missing something? It may be simple to you but I obviously don't see it. I'd much appreciate it if you *show* me what I'm missing.

Comment: But... but... you said it was simple. :o

Comment: It is simple, but it was simpler about 10 years ago when I was writing this sort of low-level, boring code every day. I've grown up, I've moved on, I use WCF now.

Comment: BTW, while we wait for my code to finish baking, have you seen http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6xa24z5.aspx?

Comment: Yes, I have seen their asynchronous socket examples which is similar to what I have except I keep my payloads in byte format whereas they use a string builder. Unless I missed something, their examples do not deal with fragmentation. The only method I'm really interested in is 'ReadCallback' and the one they have is also similar to the pseudo code I gave.

Comment: They don't deal with fragmentation because there is none at this level. You'll never see fragmentation. What you _will_ see is the sockets layer handing you an arbitrary number of bytes at a time - whatever it feels like. This will have nothing to do with fragmentation on the network. It will be more a matter of the internal buffer handling of the sockets layer.

Comment: I see your implementation is done differently from the asynchronous socket server example on MDSN (it uses the BeginReceive and EndReceive method I'm using--and will be moving away from). The basic concept should still apply I think. I still don't see how fragmented packets are dealt with as your code appears to be doing roughly the same my pseudo code did.

Comment: You're not listening. The Receive method does not return packets. You will never see packets. You will only receive bytes. Packet boundaries are hidden from you. Are you familiar with the TCP protocol and the way it does retries using a window of bytes? Consider that if you were seeing packets, you could see the same bytes several times. That does not make sense, so you are only given good bytes, when the network stack feels like it.

Comment: We're talking about TCP/IP networking, and you say "fragmented packets". How else am I to take you? What do you mean by "fragmented" if you're not talking about the fact that a TCP message may be split across multiple IP packets?

Comment: I think what's happened is that you are taking me literally during the instances I say packet. I am receiving bytes. Just take a look at the pseudo code! It's dealing with bytes. If I just use Receive as you are doing it's easier but I'm not just using Receive. I'm using BeginReceive and EndReceive. Please use MDSN's example to build from on dealing with fragmentation (and maybe keep things in byte format instead of using the stringbuilder) if that'll help you see where I'm coming from.

Comment: Oh, didn't noticed your reply there when I replaced my own. What I mean is given this -> 224TEST3foo3bar <-- sometimes I will get 224TEST3foo3bar or 224TEST3foo3bar224TEST3foo3bar or 224TEST3foo3bar224TEST3foo <-- in the receive buffer. Notice the last one is fragmented.